# VBA - splitting a string based on length

Tags: vba, split

I have various strings in the similar format of `XXX100XXX110XXX120XXX230XXX240`

How can I split this into parts like `XXX1000` etc. without printing it on excel?

I need to store the parts as variables.

Comment: Please include the exact desired output.

Comment: assuming you'll want to do something with the splitted strings you would strongly benefit of adding them in an array vs "hardCoded" variables.

Answer (score 1):

That could be:

```vb
Value = "XXX100XXX110XXX120XXX230XXX240"

Parts = Split(Value, "XXX")

Part1 = "XXX" & CStr(Parts(1))
Part2 = "XXX" & CStr(Parts(2))
' etc.
```